# Query Builder not working if expression was separated into a few expressions

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, query-builder, doctrine-mongodb

I'm woking with the last version of the Doctrine ODM (Mongodb).

This works:

```
$items = $om->createQueryBuilder($itemClass)
    ->field('active')->equals(true)
    ->getQuery()->execute();
```

This doesn't work:

```
$items = $om->createQueryBuilder($itemClass)
    ->field('active')->equals(true);
$items->getQuery()->execute();
```

I need it to be working If I want to add dynamic parameters. Both query builders executes exactly the same query (shown in the profiler).

Am I doing something wrong or thi is a doctrine bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you simply forgot to assign the result of `execute()` back to `$items`:

```
$items = $om->createQueryBuilder($itemClass)
            ->field('active')->equals(true);
$items = $items->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: I misspelled when copied example to SO, sorry. Updated the question. Issue still exists.

Comment: You still didn't clarify "doesn't work". The two lines of code are equivalent - but you don't assign the result of ->execute back to $items.